# Taking input using for loop in python

Tags: python

```
a,b = int(i) for i in input().split()
```

Can someone explain why the above code doesn't work?

I understand I can use this to make a **list** like:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

But why doesn't it work for 2 values? If a runtime exception rises(passing more than 2 values), termination is totally legit. But the shows invalid syntax.

Comment: I cant answer your question as to why you need the brackets other than 'you do' but `a, b = [i for i in [1,2]]` does assign a value to `a` and a value to `b`

Comment: Why did you leave off the square brackets in the first example? I think `a,b = [int(i) for i in input().split()]` does what you want.

Comment: Refer to [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Hollom, Haha! that is great mate. But you are taking values from a list [1,2] iterating a list of size 2 to assign it to two values is totally explainable. Also as your list contains integer values, a and b become integers. Maybe I framed the question wrong. This essentially is the thing with the loops. (As I read now) The loop is called a generator and makes a collection of data. Maybe it can only generate data data as a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked. These are called **Generator Functions**. And the code can be modified as:

```
a,b = (int(x) for x in input().split())
```

Also, `a,b = [int(x) for x in input().split()]` also does the same job, but instead it return a list. The list is then iterated and is assigned to the variables at python's end. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Thanks to everyone who answered! :D